# How are operators with the same precedence in C evaluated?

Tags: c

In the context of C operators precedence. In reality, the following code will be evaluated as follows:

```
int32_t * result = (int32_t *) addr_base + offset;

                        |
                        |
                        ↓

int32_t * result = ((int32_t *) addr_base) + offset;
```

However, what I see in the table bellow is that `cast` and `+` should be evaluated from right to left. In other words, in my example `+` is right to `cast`, so I would expect that the first statement above will be evaluated like this:

```
int32_t * result = (int32_t *) (addr_base + offset);
```

As `+` is on the right side of `cast` (so more priority according to the table).

Why is that actually happening?

[image]

Comment: unary + vs binary +

Comment: the Associativity column refers to disambiguating amongst multiple uses of operators from the same row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` in row 2 is the **unary plus operator**. This is similar to the unary negation operator (e.g. `x = -y`)

The operator for addition is in row 4 and has a lower precedence than the cast.

In case two operators have the same precedence the order is given by the **Associativity** (left to right or right to left)

Comment: You were very specific and pointed out exactly where I should look in the table and why. You also explained simply what unary operator is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The cast operator has higher precedence than addition, so that's why the operand is grouped with the cast operator.

Unary plus has the same precedence as cast. If you were to use those in the same expression, the associativity would go from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

A cast operator has the same precedence as a unary `+` operator, but the `+` operator in `(int32_t) addr_base + offset` is a binary `+` operator, which has lower precedence.

A *unary* operator is one with only one operand. In `x = -y;`, the `-` is a unary operator. We can also write `x = +y;`, where the `+` is a unary operator, but this is rarely done since it is largely superfluous.

A *binary* operator is one with two operands. In `x = y + z`, the `+` is a binary operator.

Answer (score 1):

Although *unary* plus has the same precedence as casts, the expression in question involves binary `+`, which is two rows lower in the precedence table.  So

```
(int32_t *) addr_base + offset
```

is unambiguously parsed as

```
((int32_t *) addr_base) + offset
```